# Why my iphone get off when I plug into the charger and get on when I unplug

Tags: iphone, charging

I am using iPhone XS max, since recently I have been facing problem with charging the phone, my phone get off soon when I plug into the charger, however if my phone is active (call is on or video is running etc.) even while charging the phone doesn’t get off.

Similarly the phone will get switched ON automatically when I unplug from charger, I have tried with different charges and charging cables, still the problem remain same,

Anyone over there can help me on this?

Comment: Will the *battery* still be *charged* if the iphone switches off when plugging in the charging cable?

Comment: The battery is not charging while the phone is switched off, to keep my phone charging i run a video or play music while charging so the phone doesnt get off , can anyone suggest me a permanent solution or help me to diagnose the issue ? Thank you